# Translating a passage from Ma'asei ha-Shem

Tags: parshanut-torah-comment, commentaries, translation, parshat-korach

I'm struggling with two short phrases from the Ma'asei ha-Shem [commentary on Parashat Korach](https://michaelgraetz.com/%D7%94%D7%9C%D7%9B%D7%94-%D7%95%D7%9E%D7%93%D7%A8%D7%A9/%D7%95%D6%B7%D7%99%D6%BC%D6%B8%D7%9E%D6%B9%D7%93%D6%BC%D7%95%D6%BC-%D7%91%D6%B8%D7%A2%D6%B9%D7%9E%D6%B6%D7%A8-%D7%9C%D7%99%D7%9E%D7%95%D7%93-%D7%9C%D7%9B%D7%9C-%D7%99%D7%95%D7%9D-%D7%91%D7%A2%D7%95/). I've bolded the relevant bits below, can anyone help?

אשמים אנחנו כאשר נתרשל מלחקור בסתרי תורתנו באמרנו כבר אריות גברו **ונקבל דבריהם כפי מה שהם ואפילו שהם חלוקים בדבריהם**, על כל אחד נאמר מי יחלוק על הארי הזה, **ועל הדרך הזה נניח הקודמים לנו חלוקים בעיסתם באמרנו פן ירוצו את גולגלתנו**, שאין ספק כי כל עושה אלה עליו נאמר "אמר עצל ארי בחוץ בתוך רחובות ארצח" (משלי כב, יג).

Shabbat shalom!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ונקבל דבריהם כפי מה שהם ואפילו שהם חלוקים בדבריהם - And we will accept their words at face value even although they disagree.

ועל הדרך הזה נניח הקודמים לנו חלוקים בעיסתם באמרנו פן ירוצו את גולגלתנו - Accordingly we will not attempt to resolve their differences (i.e. we will accept their unresolved opinions) lest they smash our skulls (i.e. lest they point out that we have "no idea" and are not qualified to qualify what they are saying).

Comment: I would add to the first phrase "although they disagree with each other"

Comment: The main point of the second phrase is that we leave the earlier ones disagreeing with each other, without performing an analysis and concluding in favor of one view over the other.

Comment: Thanks pcoz and Joel K, this makes some sense. What is that word עיסתם though?

Comment: @zarka It's a talmudic phrase meaning "they divide their dough", in the context of partners who do not share food. See e.g. Bava Batra 52b. I'm not really sure why it gets borrowed here to mean "they are in disagreement".